# Error get image from url using curl?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
admin
-index.php
uploads
```

in index.php i using code:

```
function saveImageFromUrl($my_img, $fullpath){
   if($fullpath!="" && $fullpath){
      $fullpath = $fullpath."/".basename($my_img);
   }
   $ch = curl_init ($my_img);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close ($ch);
   if(file_exists($fullpath)){
      unlink($fullpath);
   }
   $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
   fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
   fclose($fp);
}
$dir = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$fullpath = "uploads";
saveImageFromUrl('image.png', $dir.$fullpath);
```

And result error get image fail => how to fix it ?

Comment: When you call `saveImageFromUrl` in the last line, the $my_img you provided is not a valid URL. Also, if you `echo $dir.$fullpath;` at the end, is the result a valid path? Why using several `dirname()`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//$dir = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$fullpath = "../uploads";
saveImageFromUrl('image.png', $fullpath);
```